# Laravel Queue mail doesn't work, but send mail works

Tags: laravel

i have a very strange problem.
If i use laravel send mail everything works perfect.
but when i queue a mail it give a this error.
but the very strange part is, that yesterday my code did work!! without changing anything now

this works:

```
    Mail::send('emails.empty',
        $invoice, function ($m) use ($invoice) {

            $m->from('hello@app.com', 'Your Application');
            $m->to($invoice['customer_email'], $invoice['customer_name'])
                ->subject($invoice['email_subject']);
        });
```

But this doesn't work

```
    Mail::later(1, 'emails.empty',
        $invoice, function ($m) use ($invoice) {

            $m->from('hello@app.com', 'Your Application');
            $m->to($invoice['customer_email'], $invoice['customer_name'])
                ->subject($invoice['email_subject']);
        });
```

Also with the new 5.3 way it doesn't work

```
$user = new App\User();
        $user = $user->find(1);
        Mail::to($user)->queue(new EmailTest($user));
```

This is the faild job error:

```
Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message "" in /private_html/dev1/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:383
Stack trace:
#0 .......................
```

I use mailtrap to send/catch my emails. with the same settings de SEND function works! so its not the settings

Comment: What's your queue driver?

Comment: QUEUE_DRIVER="database"